# Login via twitter on iOS and authenticate on my server

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a web service that uses twitter. I want the user to be able to signin through the native twitter accounts on iOS. Then use the credentials to sign in to the website.

Can I just sent the authToken and authTokenSecret to my server? Are there any security risks?

This is a common question but I ask this again because twitter's [reverse auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) seems to have disappeared

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any other solution than passing these pieces of information to your server. The recommended flow is the following:

> - Get AuthToken and AuthTokenSecret on iOS device
> - Send these two values to your server
> - Your server must ask Twitter about these credentials to confirm (or not) the user authenticity

Concerning eventual security risks, it's a good practice to use [SSL encryption](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for your client-server communications.

Comment: How is that different from the browser signin flow? That must send the same information.